# limit mousemove to one element

Tags: jquery, meteor

This Meteor client event swipes the element with the class `swipe` which works fine.  The Problem I am having is while the mouse left button is still pressed and moves to another element "un intentionally" with the same class, the second element start responding to the mousemove as well.

I need the mousemove to stick to one element at a time as this code is part of rolling my own swipe code which swipes `<p>` elements out to the right of the screen. All the elements have the same class.  How can this problem be fixed?  Thanks

```js
Template.swipe.events({
  'mousemove .swipe': function (event) {
    let moveBy = utility.swipeRight(event.clientX);
    if (!moveBy) return;
    $(event.target).offset({left: moveBy});
  }
});
```

```html
<template name="swipe">
  {{#each items}}
     <p class="whole swipe" data-id={{this.index}}>{{{value}}}</p>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Mousemove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousemove) event is fired when mouse moves while over an element. Your event is fired when mouse moves while over any swipe element regardless if that element is "active" or not. (If I understand your example correctly, it even fires regardless of mouse button being down or not.)

One simple solution would be to add an additional css class to an element when mousedown event occurs on that element and to handle mousemove event only on elements with that additional class. For example:

```
Template.swipe.events({
    'mousedown .swipe': function(event){
        $(event.target).addClass('active');
    },
    'mouseup': function(event){
        $('.swipe').removeClass('active');
    },
    'mousemove .swipe.active': function (event) {
        //same code
    }
});
```

Be sure to remove additional class when mouse is up. Bear in mind that you must handle mouseup on any element because mouse could move away from all 'swipe' elements while swiping (just as it is moved to a different element which caused your initial problem).